# What exactly is PATH_INFO in PHP?

Tags: php, pathinfo

> all external URLs look like 'module/action?key1=param1'. No customization possible--but it's fast.
>   The difference is that the first uses PHP's GET, and the second uses PATH_INFO.

I've seen `PATH_INFO` several times, but still don't know what exactly it is. What does it do?

Comment: `https://web.host/index.php/path/info` PATH_INFO means the string after index.php

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Actually, `PATH_INFO` is related to the Apache Web Server serving PHP pages and not PHP per se.

`PATH_INFO` is an environment variable set by Apache when the [`AcceptPathInfo` directive](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#acceptpathinfo) is turned on. It will contain trailing pathname information that follows an actual filename or non-existent file in an existing directory, whether the request is accepted or rejected. Environment variables are then passed on to the Apache/CGI module in charge of rendering the page.

The variable is accessible in PHP using `$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']`.

For example, assume the location `/test/` points to a directory that contains only the single file `here.html`. Then requests for `/test/here.html/more` and `/test/nothere.html/more` both collect `/more` as `PATH_INFO`.

> [Apache Core Documentation: `AcceptPathInfo` Directive](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#acceptpathinfo)

Comment: After reading your answer, one could infer it's a bad practice to rely on PATH_INFO and it isn't. PATH_INFO is part of of the definition for CGI (as SimonSinCity pointed). It is supported by most web server, not just Apache.

Answer (score 26):

As the variable PATH_INFO is part of the definition for CGI you should also take a look in there ;)

> The PATH_INFO variable specifies a path to be interpreted by the CGI
> script.  It identifies the resource or sub-resource to be returned by
> the CGI script, and is derived from the portion of the URI path
> hierarchy following the part that identifies the script itself.
> Unlike a URI path, the PATH_INFO is not URL-encoded, and cannot
> contain path-segment parameters.  A PATH_INFO of "/" represents a
> single void path segment.
>
> ```
>  PATH_INFO = "" | ( "/" path )
>  path      = lsegment *( "/" lsegment )
>  lsegment  = *lchar
>  lchar     = <any TEXT or CTL except "/">
> ```

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3875#section-4.1.5