# I do not have PATH_INFO in $ _SERVER

Tags: php

I use WampServer Version 2.2 on Windows 7, Apache version 2.2.22 and PHP version 5.3.13.

I try to use `$this->url = $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'];` in the Request file,
I received this error:

> Notice: Undefined index: PATH_INFO in C:\wamp\www\site\core\Request.php on line 8

I tried to configure the `httpd.conf` file to add AcceptPathInfo On
For PHP in `php.ini` so I added `cgi.fix_pathinfo = 1` but this did not fix the problem.

How can I fix this?

Comment: did you restart the server after adding `cgi.fix_pathinfo=1` ?

Answer (score 6):

`PATH_INFO` is undefined if you aren't using URL rewriting (or rather: referencing your PHP file 'as a directory'), see here: [What exactly is PATH_INFO in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2261951/what-exactly-is-path-info-in-php)

So if you're doing this: `GET /foo/bar.php?query=foo` then `PATH_INFO` will be undefined.

If you do this: `GET /foo/bar.php/baz?query=foo` then `PATH_INFO` will be defined as `/baz`.

Answer (score 3):

> for example **`ROOT = 'C:\wamp\www\mySite'`**

it may be helpful to you to get the same result (**`$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']`**) if you use this code:

```
<?php
    class App{
        public static function get__PATH_INFO($path){
            $path_elements = explode("/", $path);
            $tempPI = "";
            if (isset($path_elements[2])){
                for ($i = 2 ;$i < count($path_elements); $i++ )
                    $tempPI .= "/".$path_elements[$i];
            }
            return $tempPI;
        }
    }
?>
```

then you call the function **`get__PATH_INFO()`** in another file:

```
$path_info = App::get__PATH_INFO($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this instead of $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'] (it's work for me)

> $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'] is original version of 'PATH_INFO' before processed by PHP.

```
$_SERVER['ORIG_PATH_INFO']
```

OR:

```
$Path_Info = isset($_SERVER['PATH_INFO']) ? $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'] : (isset($_SERVER['ORIG_PATH_INFO']) ? $_SERVER['ORIG_PATH_INFO'] : '');
```

Answer (score 1):

Just faced the same Problem that for localhost there is no PATH_INFO. But there is a way to make it work using the PHP parse_url function (see [PHP: parse_url - documentation](http://php.net/manual/de/function.parse-url.php))

```
parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH)
```

If you use this for `https://example.org/example#stuff?q=1` it will return `/example`

Comment: It worths noting that this going to return the script name too if present (ie. such as "index.php"), so cannot be assumed as reliable `$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']` replacement.

Answer (score 0):

$_SERVER['PATH_INFO'] is not available if you are calling your URL as http://localhost/.

If you upload this script to a server and call it by its name this same variable will become available automatically.

Comment: I disagree. PATH_INFO is available in localhost too: I made a whole framework on top of it, which runs in localhost as well. Maybe your problem lies in elsewhere in your configurations or calling conventions.