# Difference between baseUrl and pathInfo in Yii

Tags: php, yii

What is the exact difference between `Yii::app()->getRequest()->pathInfo` and `Yii::app()->getRequest()->baseUrl` in Yii? Examples would help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What exactly is PATH\_INFO in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2261951/what-exactly-is-path-info-in-php)

Comment: No this is Yii-specific.

Comment: Right, this is not a duplicate. Please do **not** close.

Answer (score 4):

**pathInfo** [Yii Class Referenсe | CHttpRequest#pathInfo](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHttpRequest#pathInfo-detail)

> Returns the path info of the currently requested URL. This refers to the part that is after the entry script and before the question mark. The starting and ending slashes are stripped off.

E.g. your URL looks like

```
http://example.com/index.php/abc/def/?qwe=123
```

Then your "pathInfo" will look like

```
abc/def
```

**baseUrl** [Yiic Class Referenсe | CHttpRequest#baseUrl](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHttpRequest#baseUrl-detail)

> Returns the relative URL for the application. This is similar to scriptUrl except that it does not have the script file name, and the ending slashes are stripped off.

To understand it please refer to [CHttpRequest](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHttpRequest) docs and to [$_SERVER](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) docs.

```
public function getBaseUrl($absolute=false)
{
    if($this->_baseUrl===null)
        $this->_baseUrl=rtrim(dirname($this->getScriptUrl()),'\\/');
    return $absolute ? $this->getHostInfo() . $this->_baseUrl : $this->_baseUrl;
}
```

and

```
public function getScriptUrl()
{
    if($this->_scriptUrl===null)
    {
        $scriptName=basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']);
        if(basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'])===$scriptName)
            $this->_scriptUrl=$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'];
        elseif(basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])===$scriptName)
            $this->_scriptUrl=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
        elseif(isset($_SERVER['ORIG_SCRIPT_NAME']) && basename($_SERVER['ORIG_SCRIPT_NAME'])===$scriptName)
            $this->_scriptUrl=$_SERVER['ORIG_SCRIPT_NAME'];
        elseif(($pos=strpos($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'],'/'.$scriptName))!==false)
            $this->_scriptUrl=substr($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'],0,$pos).'/'.$scriptName;
        elseif(isset($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']) && strpos($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'],$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'])===0)
            $this->_scriptUrl=str_replace('\\','/',str_replace($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'],'',$_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']));
        else
            throw new CException(Yii::t('yii','CHttpRequest is unable to determine the entry script URL.'));
    }
    return $this->_scriptUrl;
}
```

and

> 'SCRIPT_NAME' Contains the current script's path. This is useful for
>   pages which need to point to themselves. The **FILE** constant
>   contains the full path and filename of the current (i.e. included)
>   file.
>
> 'SCRIPT_FILENAME' The absolute pathname of the currently executing
>   script.

E.g. your URL looks like

```
http://example.com/index.php/abc/def/?qwe=123
```

Then your "baseUrl" will look like empty string ("") because

```
1. $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] is "/index.php"
2. Yii::app()->request->getScriptUrl() is "/index.php"
3. Yii::app()->request->getBaseUrl() is ""
```

E.g. your URL looks like (imagine that you put your application not in a root web folder for current host but in a subfolder "customfolder")

```
http://example.com/customfolder/index.php/abc/def/?qwe=123
```

Then your "baseUrl" will look like "/customfolder" because

```
1. $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] is "/customfolder/index.php"
2. Yii::app()->request->getScriptUrl() is "/customfolder/index.php"
3. Yii::app()->request->getBaseUrl() is "/customfolder"
```

Comment: what will baseURL return for your example?

Answer (score 0):

Let me quote [my comment](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHttpRequest#c1967) from the reference manual for some examples:

In both following cases the application is installed in a subdirectory `somefolder`.

#### showScriptName=false

Browser URL: `http://www.example.com/somefolder/contact?search=term`

```
baseUrl:        /somefolder
hostInfo:       http://www.example.com
pathInfo:       contact
queryString:    search=term
requestUri:     /somefolder/contact?search=term
scriptFile:     /www/www.example.com/htdocs/somefolder/index.php
scriptUrl:      /somefolder/index.php
url:            /somefolder/contact?search=term
```

#### showScriptName=true

Browser URL: `http://www.example.com/somefolder/index.php/contact?search=term`

```
baseUrl:        /somefolder
hostInfo:       http://www.example.com
pathInfo:       contact
queryString:    search=term
requestUri:     /somefolder/index.php/contact?search=term
scriptFile:     /www/www.example.com/htdocs/somefolder/index.php
scriptUrl:      /somefolder/index.php
url:            /somefolder/index.php/contact?search=term
```