# What happens when i put a slash (/) after a .php url?

Tags: php, url, http-status-code-404, slash

I have a simple question, but could not find the answer anywhere

say I have a site "mysite.com". 
I can access the index page by either typing "mysite.com" or "mysite.com/index.php".
This works fine... however, when i try to go to "mysite.com/index.php/" the page loads, but not correctly.
what is exactly happening? I would think it should return a 404 error, since index.php would be treated as a (non existing) directory (i.e. i would think it would try to find "mysite.com/index.php/index.php").
This clearly isn't the case.  Can someone please tell me what exactly is happening?
This is also true when you put anything after the slash, i.e. "mysite.com/index.php/hello"

thanks.

Comment: It's just treated as PATH_INFO. The virtual path fragment however breaks relative resource links (css, images).

Comment: thanks for the reply. i still don't quite understand. whats is the point of allowing such a url to be valid in the first place? why not just return 404 error?

Answer (score 4):

This is due to your Apache environmental variable called PATH_INFO.

**PATH_INFO**

Actually, PATH_INFO is related to the Apache Web Server serving PHP pages and not PHP per-say.

PATH_INFO is an environment variable set by Apache when the AcceptPathInfo directive is turned on. It will contain trailing pathname information that follows an actual filename (or non-existent file in an existing directory) will be accepted or rejected. Environment variables are then passed on to the Apache/CGI module in charge of rendering the page.

The variable is accessible in PHP using $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'].

For example, assume the location /test/ points to a directory that contains only the single file here.html. Then requests for /test/here.html/more and /test/nothere.html/more both collect /more as PATH_INFO.

This answer is copied from Andrew Moore 
[Link to original  answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2261951/what-exactly-is-path-info-in-php)

Comment: Is this really unique to Apache? NGINX won't do the same thing?

Comment: Attribution is required if you copy from other answers.

Comment: Please see [citation advise](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/115816/how-should-i-attribute-excerpts-of-code-from-other-stack-overflow-posts/115820#115820). At the very least mention the author, and don't hide it in an undescriptive Link below the verbatim copy.

Answer (score 1):

When the server notices that a "directory" in the URL is a script rather than an actual directory, it runs the script. The remaining components of the path in the URL are put in the PHP variable `$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']`.