# .htaccess rewrite rule breaks css and javascript when non existant sub directory or trailing slash is in url

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I noticed that adding a trailing / to index.php breaks css and javascript which was explained here- [what-happens-when-i-put-a-slash-after-a-php-url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21299243/what-happens-when-i-put-a-slash-after-a-php-url)

My rewrite rule takes whatever string is after the domain and a forward slash and puts it into the GET variable q. So foo.com/foo works fine and I can access /foo in the GET variable q. How do I get any non existent resource requested in url string to work similarly? Make foo.com/foo/ OR foo.com/foo/foo etc. redirect to index.php and not break css and javascript.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php?q=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

**My rewrite rule works when a query string is appended to index.php or when /index.php is replaced with /foo but breaks js and css when additional directories are added like /foo/ or /foo/foo. How does the rule need to be written to prevent this?**

Comment: put a example of yours css or js files' url

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="js/search.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css"/>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you use relative links for including your javascript or css files.
So, all you have to do is make your file addresses absolute, like `/js/search.js`.
Your rewrite rule is correct and it won't forward the actual files to your index.php file. But when you say `src='js/search.js'`, it means *index.php/js/search.js* for the browser, and that is not an actual file address.

Comment: Instead of changing relative paths to absolute, I found the answer in a similar question by adding this to the head <base href="http://localhost/Foo/" /> Now everything works as expected. Thanks!