# Rewrite rule for same page, multiple variables

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

My index page's URL can contain multiple different variables, like:

```
index.php?page=page1
index.php?page=page2
index.php?page=page3
index.php?page=page4
```

How would I use .htaccess to shorten these URLs so that they look like this:

```
index.php/page1
index.php/page2
index.php/page3
index.php/page4
```

Thanks.

Comment: please, let us know if an answer solved your question. If so, please mark the question as 'solved', so help you others !

Answer (score 0):

You do not need rewrite rule for this. 
[What exactly is PATH_INFO in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2261951/what-exactly-is-path-info-in-php)

Just look at `$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']`

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the following code in .htaccess to generate friendly urls (this is what you need to search for if you want to know more about this):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php?page=$1
```

this will let you use

```
yourdomain.com/page1 => yourdomain.com/index.php?page=page1
yourdomain.com/page2 => yourdomain.com/index.php?page=page2
yourdomain.com/page3 => yourdomain.com/index.php?page=page3
yourdomain.com/...   => yourdomain.com/index.php?page=...
```