# Why same .htaccess commands working differently in localhost and server?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have the following .htaccess command for redirection of php pages

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

This code is working in localhost.It is not working in web server. But  when code is slightly modified it works in server.

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: The first url uses something called path info. The second url uses the query string. I assume that you are using a framework of some kind?

Comment: No I am doing url rewriting for my core php project

Comment: possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2261951/what-exactly-is-path-info-in-php

Comment: When i have changed the rule  I have to use parse_url function so that I haven't get any values through $_GET method

Comment: Well, you do not pass a key-value pair as the query-string, so `$_GET` does not contain anything useful. If you would use `?url=/$1` you could use `$_GET["url"]`.

Comment: I wonder how the 1st code works on localhost. index.php/any probably doesn't exist and you must get the 404 error.

Comment: No. Its working in localhost... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason this is happening is because you probably have different **PHP versions** running. I believe this has been considered a PHP bug for some time but don't quote me on that. You might be running an earlier version of PHP (Like maybe 5.2.X) on your localhost and newer on your web server. It's not an `.htaccess` issue. It's PHP. You just have to know which one to use depending on the version.

Take this answer for reference as well.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4365161/330987