# Detect a URL that only contains query vs has subdirectories in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I need to run a function on a URL that *doesn't* contain subdirectories - one that *only* applies to the root domain, but where the root domain can have query string.

For example, this should match:

- domain.com
- domain.com?utm=blah
- domain.com/?utm=blah

It shouldn't match:

- domain.com/directory

(I can't just check for a `/` since that's technically included in even a URL on the root domain.)

I imagine I can get fancy with splitting the URL and all, but wondering if there's an easier way to say, "If the URL after '.com/' either doesn't exist or doesn't start with `?`"...

Comment: jQuery is not JavaScript. jQuery is a library for querying the DOM, not the URL.

Comment: Are you trying to specifically detect sub-directories or any non-empty path?

Answer (score 1):

You can parse the URLs with the [URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL) class and extract the [pathname](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/pathname) property. If the pathname is longer than `"/"`, then it has a non-empty path

```js
const urls = [
  "https://example.com",
  "https://example.com?utm=blah",
  "https://example.com/?utm=blah",
  "https://example.com/index.html?utm=blah",
  "https://example.com/directory"
];

urls.forEach((url) => {
  const parsed = new URL(url);
  const hasPath = parsed.pathname.length > 1;
  console.log(url, "has path:", hasPath);
});
```

Note, this produces false positives for URLs with [PATH_INFO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2261951/283366), eg `https://example.com/index.html/foo/bar/baz` but it's not clear if you need that level of support.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want

```js
window.location.pathname === '/'
```

`pathname` will be `/` if you're at `https://www.google.com`, but it'll be `/search` if you're at `https://www.google.com/search?q=foo`

Answer (score -1):

I believe the solution can be found at the following fine URL:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/42353290/1132976

Basically, check to see if `window.location.search` is a valid object. There is discussion on how to iterate on the values within the object at that article.

PS: This probably won't work on really old browsers. YMMV.

Comment: `search` is the query string. I think OP is talking about the path. "valid object" is weird verbiage. It's a string. It'll either be an empty string, or contain the part after and including `?`

Comment: The link in the answer shows using the `window.location.search` in the constructor of a `URLSearchParams` object. The example provided allows for a great deal of flexibility in parsing the query string, even though the OP might not need that.